# Organic Groups Views contextual filter is not working

Tags: organic-groups, views

I am trying to make a view in which I have to show images from an image-field of an organic group content type. I have tried for many hours but I am unable to make it work. I am trying to explain the scenario:

I have a venue (organic group) content type. For each venue there is an image field which can hold multiple images. I want to show a list of images that belong to a specific venue. For that I have to make a view so that I can show a list of images belonging to that specific venue. I have used the following path string:

```
/group/%/images
```

Now what I want is that for example, I want to visit a "pizza-house" venue, then the path string of the view will be:

```
/group/pizza-house/images
```

Now on this page I only want to show images from multiple image-field that only belong to "pizza-house" venue (Venue content type contains that field).  For achieving this, I have tried the following contextual filter and relationships as in shown the pictures but of no use :/
[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]
[image: pic 4]
Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I am new to contextual filters and  organic groups.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "pizza-house" stand for? Is it somehow related to the group? The contextual filter has to take its value from somewhere, and I would have thought you'd get it from that parameter in the path, but that won't work the way you've set it up.

Comment: pizza-house is actually an URL-alias for the venue group type generated by pathauto. The main problem is that I am unable to figure out which contextual filter and relationship would I use to get correct results. I have updated the post with another picture, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it took me hours to finally find this solution:
http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2013/05/sneaky-previously-undocumented-views-feature

I know it's for overriding the title, but it worked for me when I wanted to display a certain content type in a view for a specific group based on what page I was on. I fiddled for quite some time with relationships and different combos. But, all you need is the contextual filter: OG Membership: Group ID with a default value provided (current OG group from context) and specify validation criteria (OG GrouP).

Hope this helps!